# React-Native Expo works fine but the apk doesn't work when I try to navigate to a specific screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a react-native app using expo. It's working absolutely fine in expo. But whenever I am building the apk from it, one specific navigation is not working and the app is getting closed (Not being uninstalled) from the device.
What could be the reason for it?
Note that, other routings are working fine.

Here is the app.json file.

```
{"expo": {
    "name": "SudokuForever",
    "slug": "SudokuForever",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.brainless_loco.SudokuForever"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "e9903aae-5949-4a6c-9de8-ccb0dab1b3d7"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The routing:

```
 <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
          name="LogIn"
          component={LogIn}
          options={{headerShown:false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignUp"
          component={SignUp}
          options={{headerShown:false}}
        />
      <Stack.Screen
          name="HomeScreen"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{headerShown:false}}
        />
      <Stack.Screen
          name="About"
          component={AboutSudokuForever}
          options={{headerShown:false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

I am trying to navigate to AboutSudokuForever from HomeScreen.